# group_names variable in When conditional problem

Tags: ansible

Am working on an ansible Playbook. Before the playbook there is a selection of the group that will used.

My problem is the When conditional with the group_names ansible variable, used together i get the output:

```
TASK [task in group1] *****************************************************
16:28:58
  fatal: [server1]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'group_names == group1' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (group_names == group1): 'group1' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/directory/ansible/tasks/my_playbook.yml': line 12, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: task in group1\n      ^ here\n"}
```

this is my playbook:

```
---

- name: "playbook name"
  hosts: group1:group2:group3
 

  tasks:
    - name: task 1
      command:  echo "first task"
     
    - name: task in group1
      command: echo "group1"
      when:  group_names == group1

    - name: task in group2
      command: echo "group2"
      when:  group_names == group2

    - name: task in group3
      command: echo "group3"
      when:  group_names == group3
```

My host.ini file

```
[group1]
server1
server2
server3

[group2]
server4
server5
server6

[group3]
server7
server8
server9

[group1:vars]
ansible_user=remote
ansible_password=55h_pa$$w0rd
ansible_ssh_port=22
ansible_ssh_user=sshuser
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/directory/.ssh

[group2:vars]
ansible_user=remote
ansible_password=55h_pa$$w0rd
ansible_ssh_port=22
ansible_ssh_user=sshuser
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/directory/.ssh

[group3:vars]
ansible_user=remote
ansible_password=55h_pa$$w0rd
ansible_ssh_port=22
ansible_ssh_user=sshuser
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/directory/.ssh
```

Any idea of what have i done wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried a `debug` of `group_names`? It is a list, so your comparison doesn't work. You are looking for a condition like `'group1' in group_names`.

Answer (score 4):

In your example, the group name should be quoted - `when: group_names == 'group1'`. This is what the error is complaining about.

But...

The `group_names` special variable is a list. So running a comparison (`==`) to match with a string will fail anyway. You need to use the list comparison `in` for this.

Example:

```yaml
    - name: task in group1
      debug: 
        msg: I am in group1
      when: "'group1' in group_names"
```